# Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsText is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have two HTML pages, one in which a file is uploaded and another in which the file is read.

Here is the page where it is uploaded:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function set_file() {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
            localStorage.file_input = document.getElementById("file_input").files[0];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='pagetwo.html'>
        File: <input type="file" id="file_input">

        <input type="submit" value="run" onclick="set_file()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the file in which it is read:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(localStorage.file_input); // This causes the error
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this, I get the error "Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsText is not an object". Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: You can't store objects in local storage, you can only store strings.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is there a way to pass an object from one html page to another?

Comment: You can convert it to JSON. But that won't work for `File` objects, they contain non-serializable data.

Comment: Is there any other possible way?

Comment: No. The data that a `FIle` object refers to only exists within the current page.

Comment: When you upload the file on the first page, the server should send back a token. You can put that in local storage, and then use it in the second page to download the file.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: When the file is uploaded, add a record to a database table. This record can include a unique ID, and the response to the upload can contain that ID. Then the second page can send the ID in the download request, the server script will get the filename from the database, and return the file.

Comment: So this method would involve downloading the file to the server?

Comment: I thought you were already doing that. The question says "one in which a file is uploaded". Where are you uploading it to if not the server?

Comment: Maybe I worded the question incorrectly. I just meant that I am giving the web page the input file through the <input type="file"> line.

Comment: You can't read a local file on a different page from the one where you select it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this on different pages? Why not just make this a single-page application?

Comment: I would but the actual web page is much more complicated and turning it into a single page application would go against the purpose of the project. Either way, uploading it to the server would be good either way as I will need to do so later for features that I will be implementing.